# Constant power supply with high-voltage "restrike"

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, constant-power

I'm still playing with electrolytic chemical reactors.  After looking at the results from a [constant-current circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/218976/39511) I'm realizing that what I really need is a [constant power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104953/is-there-a-constant-power-supply) because, depending on the reactor conditions and setup, it can take something like 10kV to ionize a path through the reactor and just get current running, but then the impedance collapses and what I really want to study are the results from a constant amount of *power* through the reactor over time.

Now this sounds to me roughly like what the ballast for a fluorescent light does, with two minor variations:

1. I need peak voltage to reach an order of magnitude higher
2. I need it to be able to repeatedly "strike" a high voltage, because it appears that as the reactor operates the ionized channels can collapse and have to be reopened.

So if there's an off-the-shelf (OTS) constant power supply with a voltage peak in the kV range and output in the tens of watts that would be perfect.  If some OTS item could be readily adapted to provide those characteristics please point it out (along with suggestions for modifying it appropriately).

I suspect at the very least this is something for which standard SMPS ICs could be adapted, in which case I would appreciate suggestions of the best starting point for an applied schematic.  (Source can be either 120V AC mains or any voltage DC.)

Comment: Look for an electrophoresis power supply, which can often be found used at dirt cheap prices.

Comment: @BillDubuque - Good idea!  But I just looked at the specs for a few and none approach the kV level, and they only offer constant-current or constant-voltage, not constant power.  Look like they would be great for a lot of other applications though.

Comment: Iirc some go to at least to 5kV, as searching on "electrophoresis 5000V" confirms. So try searching more.

Comment: @BillDubuque - Wow, you're right!  I apologize for my bad search skills.  Now to see if I can find one in the magical sub-$100 space, which is where I assume I could build one and write off my time as "professional skills development" ;)

Comment: There are units known as the constant intensity controller used to ensure UV power of high pressure Hg lamps remains constant for the  precise UV exposure for some chemical processes. Look for this.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.aphms.caltech.edu/documents/micro-nano-ma-power-supply-manual.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi1jrXg1-zMAhXJLY8KHXF5Ae0QFggkMAU&usg=AFQjCNFTxhLOdskfD5QmqvWs-8EPENnw-Q&sig2=5lk4HSNq4NlkBovRDWd_VQ

Comment: @soosaisteven - Very cool.  It looks like the electrophoresis units offer slightly more versatility (e.g., explicit management of current, voltage, *or* power).  I found a 3kV/150W unit for just $75!  I may still need higher peak voltage though and those high-pressure lamp supplies offer that.  I'm also still curious as to whether a boost circuit off a high-quality supply is possible at these voltage levels.